# DLRS Relationship Criteria Error - is not valid

Tags: roll-up-summary, dlrs

I am trying to filter my roll-up but I get the error that my filter is not valid. However it works on Workbench and when I query on the Dev Console

```
celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Open' OR celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Paid in Full'
```

I have also tried:

```
( celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Open' ) OR ( celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Paid in Full' )
```

And I get the same error.

It works if I only put one value, like:

```
celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Paid in Full'
Or
celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Open'
```

But not both.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it to work with either

```
celigo_sfnsio__Status__c IN ('Open','Paid in Full')
```

or

```
(celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Open' OR celigo_sfnsio__Status__c = 'Paid in Full)
```

see [WIKI relationships page](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Relationship-Criteria-(SOQL-Queries))